# Lumped mechanical system - Base Change and asymmetric matrices

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, symmetry, matrix-model

Let's assume I have a system which can be wrote as:

$$ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
        m_{1}       &   0       & \dots     &   0       \\
         0       &   m_{2}       & \dots     &   0       \\
       \vdots  &  \vdots   &   \ddots  &   \vdots  \\   
      0      &   0       & \dots     &   m_{n}         \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{M}
        \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
      \ddot{x}_{1}       \\
     \ddot{x}_{2}       \\
      \vdots  \\
       \ddot{x}_{n}      \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{\ddot{x}}
            +        
            \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    k_{1}       &   0       & \dots     &   0       \\
    0       &   k_{2}       & \dots     &   0       \\
    \vdots  &  \vdots   &   \ddots  &   \vdots  \\   
    0      &   0       & \dots     &   k_{n}         \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{K}
    \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1}       \\
    x_{2}       \\
    \vdots  \\
    x_{n}      \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{x}
    =
    \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    f_1     \\
    f_2     \\
    \vdots  \\
    f_n     \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{\mathbf{f}}$$

Now I want to study some particular relations between the system and the forces applied on him. In order to do that i take a particular pair of forces, for example: $$(f_{i},f_{j})$$

In my starting idea these are substracted, let's assume i do this with $$i=1,j=2$$ then i will introduce a base change matrix:

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
1       &   0       &   0& \dots     &   0       \\
1       &   -1       &   0& \dots     &   0       \\
0       &   0       & 1    & \dots &   0       \\
\vdots  &  \vdots   &   \vdots &   \ddots  &   \vdots  \\   
0      &   0       & \dots   & \dots  &   1         \\
            \end{bmatrix}$$

I will find then:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    f_1     \\
    f_1 - f_2     \\
    f_3    \\
    \vdots  \\
    f_n     \\
            \end{bmatrix}=B\begin{bmatrix}
    f_1     \\
    f_2     \\
    f_3\\
    \vdots  \\
    f_n     \\
            \end{bmatrix}$$

Which allows me to write a new system where the forces are now subtracted:

$$ \underbrace{B\begin{bmatrix}
        m_{1}       &   0 &   0      & \dots     &   0       \\
         0       &   m_{2}   &   0    & \dots     &   0       \\
               0   &   0    &   m_{3}      & \dots     &   0       \\
       \vdots  &  \vdots   &   \vdots  &   \ddots &   \vdots  \\   
      0      &   0 &   0      & \dots     &   m_{n}         \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{M_{asymmetric}}
        \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
      \ddot{x}_{1}       \\
     \ddot{x}_{2}       \\
     \ddot{x}_{3}       \\
      \vdots  \\
       \ddot{x}_{n}      \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{\ddot{x}}
            +        
            \underbrace{B\begin{bmatrix}
    k_{1}       &   0 &   0      & \dots     &   0       \\
         0       &   k_{2}   &   0    & \dots     &   0       \\
               0   &   0    &   k_{3}   & \dots     &   0       \\
       \vdots  &  \vdots   &   \vdots  &   \ddots &   \vdots  \\   
      0      &   0 &   0      & \dots     &   k_{n}         \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{K_{asymmetric}}
    \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1}       \\
    x_{2}       \\
     x_{3}       \\
    \vdots  \\
    x_{n}      \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{x}
    =
    \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    f_1     \\
    f_1-f_2     \\
    f_3\\
    \vdots  \\
    f_n     \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            }_{\mathbf{f}}$$

The resulting mass and stiffness matrix are not anymore symmetric. In fact these are (in the above example):
$$ M_{asymmetric}=\begin{bmatrix} m_{1}       &   0 &   0      & \dots     &   0       \\
         m_{2}       &   -m_{2}   &   0    & \dots     &   0       \\
               0   &   0    &   m_{3}      & \dots     &   0       \\
       \vdots  &  \vdots   &   \vdots  &   \ddots &   \vdots  \\   
      0      &   0 &   0      & \dots     &   m_{n} \end{bmatrix}        \\$$
$$ K_{asymmetric}=\begin{bmatrix} k_{1}       &   0 &   0      & \dots     &   0       \\
         k_{2}       &   -k_{2}   &   0    & \dots     &   0       \\
               0   &   0    &   k_{3}      & \dots     &   0       \\
       \vdots  &  \vdots   &   \vdots  &   \ddots &   \vdots  \\   
      0      &   0 &   0      & \dots     &   k_{n} \end{bmatrix}        \\$$
What's the sense of this? I found on various posts that mass matrix need to be symmetric in order to have physical meaning.
Any suggestions to work with my problem applying some different methods to get the difference of the two forces without using the base change?
Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Would you like to compute $f_1 - f_2$. If so, *why*? That value might not have physical meaning either.

Comment: I am studying my system modal behaviour (frequency response) depending on a set of forces applied. Usually this $$B$$ matrix is known as "Force distribution matrix" in mechanical of vibrations